# Extended Backus–Naur Form order of operations

Tags: language-design, grammar, rules, ebnf, operator-precedence

I am creating a formal spec for a very simple rule language, very simple.
I want to use EBNF as this is a standard but I can't figure out how to specify order of operations. Here is the specification so far.

```
rule = statement, { (‘AND’|’OR’), statement};

variable = ‘$’,alphabetic character, {alphabetic character | digit};

statement = variable, [ ‘count’,[white space ],’>’,[white space],number ];

alphabetic character = "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" | "E" | "F" | "G"
                     | "H" | "I" | "J" | "K" | "L" | "M" | "N"
                     | "O" | "P" | "Q" | "R" | "S" | "T" | "U"
                     | "V" | "W" | "X" | "Y" | "Z" ;

number = [ "-" ] , digit , { digit } ;

digit = "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9" ;

white space = ? white space characters ? ;
```

The question I have is how do I show that things in brackets should be evaluated first.
So something like this

```
$strap AND ($greenSticker count > 5 OR ($greenSticker AND $redSticker))
```

It seems like a common feature to most languages, but my Google skills are failing me and I can't seem to find an example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given this as a simplified example LL grammar:

```
expression -> (+|-|ε) term ((+|-) term)*
term -> factor ((*|/) factor)*
factor -> var | number | (expression)
```

As you can see, the operators with lower precedence (`+` and `-`) are in a more general rule than the higher precedence operators (`*` and `/`). It is all about producing the correct parse tree.  But as a rule of thumb, "outer" or more general rules have less precedence, which is why the addition and subtraction operators are placed beside `term`, because `term` must be further derived. If you look at more complicated grammars you will see that this is taken into an extreme to have proper precedence.

Comment: When expressing precedence in grammar rules, I can't see why you are making a distinction between top-down and bottom-up parsing. As you said, it's all about producing the correct parse tree, and you just construct that top-down or bottom-up, to get to the same result eventually. Of course this has a few implications, but it is not obvious to me how you are relating the parsing technique to (this kind of) precedence. Please explain.

Comment: That expression grammar will work in a bottom-up parser too, and in a top-down LL parser as well, not just in recursive-descent parsers. A Pratt parser is recursive-descent and top-down too. Your second paragraph really doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: To address both of your issues, I have just removed the confusing paragraph. I hope the rest of my answer is beneficial!

Comment: this makes sense but i'm still a little confused. when a parser looks at `3 + 4 * 5`, how does it know not to evaluate `3 + 4` as "expression" first, then evaluate that `expression` as "factor" next, and then evaluate `factor * 5` as "term" last? Does it have anything to do with the *order* of your statements?

Comment: @chharvey Yes, it has to do with the order. The rules further down the grammar (i.e., closer to the terminals, like `number`) have a higher precedence. So * and / have higher precedence than + and -. Take your example and try manually parsing it using my grammar.

Comment: @AustinHenley I did: it still works even though it shouldn't: `3 -> number -> factor -> term[1] ; 4 -> number -> factor -> term[2] ; term[1] + term[2] -> expression -> factor[3] ; 5 -> number -> factor[4] ; factor[3] * factor[4] -> term ;` Am I missing something?